# How to access a specific subclasses methods in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi I have a class **Property** and 2 subclasses **Shop** and **Apartment**.

In another class I have an arraylist of properties with a mixture of shops and apartments. I have the code:

```
for(Property prop: properties){
  if(prop.getClass().equals(Shop.class))
       prop.setShopDetails(detail);
  else
       prop.setAppDetails(detail)
}
```

How can I access the method setShopDetails() inside the shop class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast `prop` to a `Shop`:

```
for(Property prop: properties){
  if(prop.getClass().equals(Shop.class))
       ((Shop) prop).setShopDetails(detail);
  else
       ((Apartment) prop).setAppDetails(detail)
  }
}
```

A better approach, however, would be to define an abstract method `setDetails` in the `Property` class and implement it differently in each subclass. You might also want to use `prop instanceof Shop` instead of `prop.getClass().equals(Shop.class)`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, consider the case where `prop` is a subclass of `Shop`. Your if condition would return `false`! This is the perfect time to use the [instanceof operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

In order to access those methods, you need to cast your object to the correct subclass:

```
if(prop instanceof Shop) {
    Shop s = (Shop) prop;
    s.setShopDetails(details);
} else {
    // you get the idea
}
```

However, this kind of defeats the purpose of polymorphism. Why not create a `setDetails` method in `Property` and allow subclasses to handle it how they will?

Answer (score 0):

First, the fact that you have to call `getClass()` in this situation usually indicates faulty design. You probably want to have a single `abstract` `setDetails` method that is overridden by the subclasses.

The language feature you are looking for is "casting". Before calling a subclass method, you want to cast your `Property` like so:

`((Shop)prop).getShopDetails(detail);`